# Splitting an array into subarrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of chars that looks like this:

```
chars = ["x", "o", "o", "x", "x", "o", "o", "x", "x", "x", "o", "o"]
```

I need to get the number of consecutive chars and the index of that char. It should look like this:

```
[
  { index: 0, length: 1 },  # "x"
  { index: 1, length: 2 },  # "o", "o"
  { index: 3, length: 2 },  # "x", "x"
  { index: 5, length: 2 },  # "o", "o"
  { index: 7, length: 3 },  # "x", "x", "x"
  { index: 10, length: 2 }  # "o", "o"
]
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Please show what you've attempted.

Comment: What are the `x`s and `o`s? Are they local variables? Or something else?

Comment: those are just chars 'x' and 'o'

Comment: @Skodik.o how would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you'd call this an easy way, but here's a one-line way of doing it. Resulting array is of the form `[index, length]`.

```
chars.each_with_index.chunk {|i, _| i}.map {|_, y| [y.first.last, y.length]}
#=> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [5, 2], [7, 3], [10, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two others ways of doing it:

**Use Emumerable#slice_when (v.2.2+)**

```
count = 0
arr = chars.slice_when { |a,b| a != b }.map do |arr|
  sz = arr.size
  h = { index: count, length: sz }
  count += sz  
  h
end
  #=> [{:index=>0, :length=>1}, {:index=>1, :length=>2}, {:index=>3, :length=>2},
  #    {:index=>5, :length=>2}, {:index=>7, :length=>3}, {:index=>10, :length=>2}]
```

**Use a regex with a backreference**

```
count = 0
arr = chars.join.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map do |run, _|
  sz = run.size
  h = { index: count, length: sz }
  count += sz
  h
end
  #=> [{:index=>0, :length=>1}, {:index=>1, :length=>2}, {:index=>3, :length=>2},
  #    {:index=>5, :length=>2}, {:index=>7, :length=>3}, {:index=>10, :length=>2}]
```